# Rails collection_select passing id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've read a bunch of questions but none of them are helping me with this problem. I am trying to create a form to make new forums but cannot get them to use the right category id.

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
```

This creates a new forum but the id is not the category id from the drop down list. Here is the forums model

```
def new
    @forum = Forum.new
  end

  def create
    @forum = Forum.new(forum_params)
    if @forum.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

   def forum_params
      params.require(:forum).permit(:category_id, :name, :description )
    end

end
```

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. Is it something to do with the foreign key? Any help would really be appreciated.

UPDATE

Forum Model

```
class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :forums, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Please include your Forum and Category models code

Comment: the `:category_id` value of new forum is `nil` or some other random value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is basically no `category_id` in the `Forum` model.

Here is a couple of things you can do to troubleshoot this. Run:

```
rails dbconsole
.schema
```

Check to see if you have `category_id` or not. If not, create a new migration for this.

Your initial code is correct. For some reason, I misread that your `collection_select` was already bound to the model.

Comment: This gives me the error

    undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol

That's something to do with my form_for(@forum) I think I'll look into what I can do to fix that.

Comment: If I change f.collection_select to collection_select I don't get an error but the forum category still isn't the one from the drop down list it's the same as the forum id.

Comment: My bad, looks like there is something with your relationships. Let me change my answer.

Comment: Oh wow. That was a little bit dumb. Thank you so much for your help. One of these days I'll be a good rails programmer and be able to help others like you are. Thank you thank you